# Render winform behind xna sprite

Tags: c#, winforms, xna, browser

I've rendered a web browser to xna but how do I render it behind things? I can render it on the top level but that's no good as I need to be able to render over it.
Initialize

```
  web = new GeckoWebBrowser();
  web.Width = 600;
  web.Height = 300;
  form.Controls.Add(web);
  web.Navigate("www.google.co.uk", GeckoLoadFlags.FirstLoad);
  web.Focus();
```

Draw

```
 try
        {
            lock (Manager)
            {

                SpriteBatch spriteBatch = ScreenManager.SpriteBatch;
                //ScreenManager.GraphicsDevice.Clear(ClearOptions.Target, Color.White, 0, 0);
                Manager.BeginDraw(gameTime);
                Manager.Draw(gameTime);
                //ScreenManager.GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0] = SamplerState.PointClamp;
                spriteBatch.Begin();
                spriteBatch.Draw(DesktopBackground,
                    new Rectangle(0, 0, ScreenManager.Game.Window.ClientBounds.Width, ScreenManager.Game.Window.ClientBounds.Height), Color.White);
                spriteBatch.End();
                Manager.EndDraw();

                if (ScreenManager.client != null)
                {
                    if (ScreenManager.client.ClientStatus())
                    {


                        spriteBatch.Begin();
                        _taskbar.DrawTaskBar(spriteBatch);
                        _taskbar.DrawIcons(spriteBatch);
                        _taskbar.DrawMovingIcon(spriteBatch);
                        ContexMenuManager.Draw(spriteBatch);
                        spriteBatch.End();
                        _taskbar.DrawStartMenu(spriteBatch);

                    }
                }


                if (!LogingIn)
                {
                    //Handle loading server
                    Loading.Draw(ScreenManager.SpriteBatch);
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteError(ex);
        }
```

this is part of the draw code how would I render the window behind some of the elements in xna.

Comment: how do we know.. we can't currently see what it is you are trying to do as well as what you have implemented so far.. please improve this question... show some code examples of where exactly you're experiencing the issue and or problems as well as all relevant code that pertains to your issue.

Comment: your question and question title doesn't make sense together..

Comment: Just to be clear, is this a WinForms app that you are rendering a XNA surface to? Or an XNA app hosting a winForms control?

Comment: If you're just trying to put a web browser "behind" a transparent backed XNA surface using the winforms layout, I wouldn't think it would work. You'll probably need to capture one or the other into an image of some sort and combine them yourself. If anyone knows any different for XNA, please correct me, but that's been my experience with other DirectX and OpenGL frameworks.

Comment: How would I also receive input when displaying the image of the control?